# What is correct way to initialize a static member of type 'T &' in a templated class?

Tags: c++, static, templates, initialization, member

I'm playing around with an eager-initializing generic singleton class. The idea is that you inherit publicly from the class like so:

```
class foo : public singleton<foo> { };
```

I've learned a lot in the process but I'm stuck right now because it's breaking my Visual Studio 2008 linker. The problem is with the static instance member and/or its initialization.

```
template<class T>
class singleton {
    singleton();
    singleton(singleton const &);
    singleton & operator = (singleton const &);
public:
    static T & instance;
};
template<class T> T & T::instance;
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

With this class declaration...

```
template<class T>
class singleton {
    singleton();
    singleton(singleton const &);
    singleton & operator = (singleton const &);
public:
    static T instance;
};
template <class T> T singleton<T>::instance;
```

When I try to do this...

```
class foo : public singleton<foo> { };
```

I get this error...

> error C2248: 'singleton::singleton'
>   : cannot access private member
>   declared in class 'singleton'
>
> ...
>
> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'foo::foo(void)'

My interpretation is that singleton wants to construct a foo object which, by inheritance, depends on the construction of a singleton whose constructor is private. I figured singleton would have access to its own constructor but I guess not. Any ideas?

EDIT 2:

I've realized that the approach of inheriting from `singleton<T>` has the problem of requiring change to the class to be used as a singleton. I've ended up with the following code for my eager-initializing singleton class template.

```
template<typename T>
class singleton_wrapper {
    singleton_wrapper();
    singleton_wrapper(singleton_wrapper const &);
    singleton_wrapper & operator = (singleton_wrapper const &);
    static T instance;
    template<typename T> friend T & singleton();
};
template<typename T> T singleton_wrapper<T>::instance;

template<typename T>
T & singleton() {
    return singleton_wrapper<T>::instance;
}
```

For class...

```
class foo {
public:
    void bar() { }
};
```

...One would access a single instance of it (initialized before main()) using the following:

```
singleton<foo>().bar();
```

Thanks again for the help, especially GMan. I'm very pleased with my first experience on stack**overflow**.

Comment: I've recently decided (\*cough\* jalf \*cough\*) to advise against making a singleton class. Global variables do work fine, without the same restrictions. For a learning exercise, please continue! But I've been convinced they are never really necessary.

Comment: Singletons are supposed to solve the undefined-iconstruction-order problem (i.e. you can't be sure what order globals are constructed in, so one global object which uses another can't be sure the object it's using is initialized) and also enforce that there is only ever a single instance.  (There's nothing stopping you from declaring another global.)

Comment: @Mike: I'm well aware of static initialization problems. A global function has the same effect without the mess. When have you ever *required* a class not be instantiated more than once?

Comment: For your edit, `singleton` *does* have access to its constructor. But it's not the one trying to construct. `foo` has to construct its base, the `singleton`, and cannot access the constructor. `singleton` needs to make `foo` it's friend. Add this in the class: `friend T;`, allowing all `T`'s to construct the singleton.

Comment: Oh wow, I had tried `friend class T;` and then read about how the standard explicitly forbids that but then I never tried `friend T`. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, though now I may be worried `friend T` is forbidden too.

Comment: Your final solution is the one I always used as well. :P (Well, a bit different but the idea is the same.) Non-intrusive options are a nice thing. Your only problem now is ensuring people cannot make `foo`'s by themselves.

Comment: What's different about your implementation, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @GMan: Ah, you were talking about global *functions*, not *variables*.  Makes much more sense.  And I've had several classes where I needed to limit the number of instances to one: manager classes and factory classes that are tied to specific hardware resources are the easy examples.

Comment: @Mike: Did those need to be limited to one, or did you just not need to make more than one? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, since you don't have a concrete instance.  You can need to create an actual instance that you can refer to:

```
template <class T>
class singleton {
    ...
private:
    static T instance_;
public:
    static T& instance;
};
template <class T> T singleton<T>::instance_;
template <class T> T& singleton<T>::instance = singleton<T>::instance;
```

Or, more simply, just ditch the reference altogether:

```
template <class T>
class singleton {
    ...
public:
    static T instance;
};
template <class T> T singleton<T>::instance;
```

Comment: Could you please improve your answer? What question does "You can't" answer?

Answer (score 1):

Off-the-sleeve: change instance to be of type 'T' instead of 'T &'.