# Initialize a templated class's static member that uses a template argument as the type?

Tags: c++, templates, static, initialization

I have:

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
class MyClass
{
     public:
     static TypeA StaticA;
     static TypeB StaticB;

     //...other stuff....
};
```

How do I initialize 'StaticA' (and StaticB)?

If I do this: (in the header file, under the class's declaration but not inside it)

```
template<>
typename MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA = TypeA();
```

Gives me:

```
'TypeA' was not declared in this scope.
'TypeB' was not declared in this scope.
template argument 1 is invalid
template argument 2 is invalid
```

And this:

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
typename MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA = TypeA();
```

Gives me:

```
conflicting declaration 'typename MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA'
'MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA' has a previous declaration as 'TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA'
declaration of 'TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA' outside of class is not definition [-fpermissive]
```

What's the proper way to initialize a templated class's static member that uses a template argument as the type?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, the correct syntax is:

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
TypeA ResourceFactory<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA = TypeA();
```

Which in my original problem is:

```
template<typename TypeA, typename TypeB>
typename MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>:: TypeA MyClass<TypeA, TypeB>::StaticA = TypeA();
^remove^ ^-------remove--------^
```

I was getting confused because of all the template arguments. =)

*Similar to, but not entirely overlapping, this question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2089068/1177073).*